# Difference between ScriptProperty and Method

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

In powershell, when I do `Get-Member` on `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem` I get a lot of members of this cmdlet.

Among them most are properties. But `ConvertToDateTime` and `ConvertFromDateTime` work like methods (they convert UNIX date/timestamp into human readable format) still they are marked as ScriptProperty.

What is the difference between a ScriptProperty and Method?

Comment: A `ScriptProperty` has up to two methods associated with it – a getter and (optionally) a setter, just like a .NET property. These methods are expressed using two scriptblocks.

Comment: But `ConvertToDateTime` and `ConvertFromDateTime` are _ScriptMethod_ membertype not _ScriptProperty_. Check the `[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]` enum…

Comment: Thanks @SimonS,JosefZ for replies.....

Answer (score 1):

**ScriptMethod**: A method that is implemented from a PowerShell Scripts.

Example:

```
$A = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\test.txt
$S = {[math]::Round(($this.Length / 1MB), 2)}
$A | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "SizeInMB" -Value $S
$A.SizeInMB()

0.4
```

**ScriptProperty**: A property defined by script language.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell `ScriptMethod` object properties are are defined using a Powershell scriptblock object with [Add-Member](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7), while [Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_methods?view=powershell-7) are defined in C# using `Add-Type -TypeDefinition 'foo'`, or through importing assemblies.

The functional differences are going to be very minor.